# test if a string is a number

Tags: erlang

How to test if a string is composed only of digits ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, using the [re](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) module:

```
1> re:run("1234a56", "^[0-9]*$").
nomatch
2> re:run("123456", "^[0-9]*$"). 
{match,[{0,6}]}
```

Or, using list comprehension:

```
[Char || Char <- String, Char < $0 orelse Char > $9] == [].
```

Note that both solutions will consider the empty list valid input.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to convert it to an integer and if that fails then you'll know it's not an integer.

```
is_integer(S) ->
    try
        _ = list_to_integer(S),
        true
    catch error:badarg ->
        false
    end.
```

Or you can just check all of the digits, but you do have to check the edge case of an empty list:

```
is_integer("") ->
    false;
is_integer(S) ->
    lists:all(fun (D) -> D >= $0 andalso D =< $9 end, S).
```

Comment: What will this do for the input "9999999999999999999999999999"?

Comment: For the input "9999999999999999999999999999" the first solution would create a big integer and then throw it away.

Comment: and with a regular expression ?

Comment: The catch clause should be :
    catch error:badarg ->
        false
    end.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [regular expression](http://schemecookbook.org/Erlang/RegexChapter).

Comment: re:match(S,"[0-9])  like this ?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I am guessing that using a regexp would be slower than using list_to_integer/1.

Comment: I'd rather not have logic that depends on throwing an exception.  Sounds like a micro-optimization to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
not lists:any(fun(C)->C < $0 or C > $9 end, YourString).
```

In production, though, I would agree with the list_to_integer as it's probably better optimized.  I'm not sure whether there are different traversal characteristics on 'any' vs 'all' either - you could implement each of them in terms of the other, but they're probably both implemented in C.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and downvote myself for writing "not lists any fun" about a functional language :D

Answer (score 1):

> Erlang doesn't come with a way to say if a string represents a numeric
>   value or not, but does come with the built-in function is_number/1,
>   which will return true if the argument passed is either an integer or
>   a float. Erlang also has two functions to transform a string to either
>   a floating number or an integer, which will be used in conjunction
>   with is_number/1.

```
is_numeric(L) ->
    Float = (catch erlang:list_to_float(L)),
    Int = (catch erlang:list_to_integer(L)),
    is_number(Float) orelse is_number(Int).
```

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Erlang